# Java - TreeMap Object as Key or Value?

Tags: java, key, treemap, comparable

I need a "Container" for a few objects. Definition:

```
class DataSet implements Comparable {
    public int id;
    public String Date;
    public double Value

    public DataSetFSA (int id, String Date) {
        this.id=id;
        this.Date=Date;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
    return  1;
    }
}
```

The objects have a certain order, which should not be destroyed! As you see my container class already has an "id" itself!

So my question is now should i insert the object as a key or a value into the TreeMap?

```
DataSet ds1 = new DataSetFSA(1,"Val1"); 
DataSet ds2 = new DataSetFSA(2,"Val2"); 
...

TreeMap DataTreeMap = new TreeMap();
        DataTreeMap.put(1,ds1); //as value
        DataTreeMap.put(2,ds2);

//or as key (then the class has to implement comparable)
        DataTreeMap.put(ds1,1); //as key but then the value doesnt has a function anymore
        DataTreeMap.put(ds2,2);
```

Comment: Why are you using a `TreeMap` at all?  What do you intend to do with it?

Comment: Why does your `compareTo` method always return 1? Are you looking to preserve the insertion order?

Comment: Well, i don't understand what you mean by: "as key but then the value doesnt has a function anymore". Also, your implementation of method 'compareTo' is 'a bit' invalid ;)

Comment: I am reading some data from a json file (containing measurements from a scientific experiment) and for each line i create a new DataSet to gather them in a TreeMap. The plan is to run some calculations on it

Comment: Exactly i am trying to preserve the insertion order! I know its a little bit invalid ;) but it was working^^

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a sorted (unique) container, there's no reason to use a `TreeMap` - a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) would seem to fit the bill perfectly.